# metafor rma.mv: no convergence with random = list(~1 |id1, ~1 | id2) but with random = list(~ id1|id2)

Tags: r, metafor

I am using metafor package in R and very interestingly, I found for the same dataset, ~id1|id2 formula seems to give fewer "no convergence" results compared to list(~1|id1, ~1|id2). Could anyone explain the reason behind it? Thank you in advance!

Here is a test data to reproduce the issue:

```
# Case 1 - different results on convergence
df <- data.frame(bac = c("a","b","c"), id2 = c("A","B","B"), id1 = c("d","e","f"), ES = c(0.5603294, -1.8397608, -1.7491630), SE=c(2.368467, 1.240960, 1.287030))

rma.mv(yi=ES, V=(SE)^2,data=df,
       random = list( ~ id1|id2),
       control = list(maxiter = 500))

rma.mv(yi=ES, V=(SE)^2,data=df, random = list(~1|id1, ~1|id2), control = list(maxiter = 500))

# Case 2: exact the same results
df2 <- data.frame(id1= c("a","b","c","d"),id2=c("c1","c1","c2","c3"), Tech= c("a1","a2","a1","a1"),ES=c(-1.5,-3,1.5,3),SE=c(.2,.4,.2,.4))
rma.mv(ES, SE^2, random = ~ id1|id2, data=df2)
rma.mv(ES, SE^2, random = list(~ 1|id1,~ 1|id2), data=df2)
```

My session information

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.1     matlib_0.9.2      magrittr_1.5      plyr_1.8.5        data.table_1.12.8
[6] metafor_2.1-0     Matrix_1.2-18     RNeo4j_1.7.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rgl_0.100.50            Rcpp_1.0.3              lattice_0.20-38         assertthat_0.2.1       
 [5] digest_0.6.23           mime_0.9                R6_2.4.1                cellranger_1.1.0       
 [9] httr_1.4.1              pillar_1.4.3            rlang_0.4.4             lazyeval_0.2.2         
[13] curl_4.3                readxl_1.3.1            rstudioapi_0.10         miniUI_0.1.1.1         
[17] car_3.0-6               webshot_0.5.2           foreign_0.8-75          htmlwidgets_1.5.1      
[21] munsell_0.5.0           shiny_1.4.0             compiler_3.6.1          httpuv_1.5.2           
[25] xfun_0.12               pkgconfig_2.0.3         htmltools_0.4.0         tidyselect_1.0.0       
[29] tibble_2.1.3            rio_0.5.16              withr_2.1.2             crayon_1.3.4           
[33] dplyr_0.8.4             later_1.0.0             MASS_7.3-51.5           grid_3.6.1             
[37] nlme_3.1-143            jsonlite_1.6.1          xtable_1.8-4            gtable_0.3.0           
[41] lifecycle_0.1.0         scales_1.1.0            zip_2.0.4               stringi_1.4.5          
[45] carData_3.0-3           promises_1.1.0          vctrs_0.2.2             openxlsx_4.1.4         
[49] tools_3.6.1             forcats_0.4.0           manipulateWidget_0.10.1 glue_1.3.1             
[53] purrr_0.3.3             hms_0.5.3               crosstalk_1.0.0         abind_1.4-5            
[57] fastmap_1.0.1           colorspace_1.4-1        knitr_1.28              haven_2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fitting these models with such small datasets is rather pointless, but in general, there isn't any particular reason why it works in one case and not in the other. Achieving convergence, esp. with such small datasets, is difficult and may work better with one model specification versus the other. In the first case, you can get it to converge by switching optimizers; for example:

```
rma.mv(yi=ES, V=(SE)^2, data=df, random = list(~1|id1, ~1|id2), control = list(optimizer="optim", optmethod="Nelder-Mead"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! @Wolfgang. I totally agree that it is a small dataset with n=3. Do you have any suggestions for the min dataset number to draw reliable conclusions?

Comment: That's a complex question and depends on many factors. Not really possible to give an answer to this in the comments (and it's really a different question than the original question anyway).

Comment: Totally understand.Thank you for the input @Wolfgang!

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are trying to improve the number of cases where convergence is achieved it helps if the model options the starting values of say tau2 are specified